# Função highcharter::hciconarray não produz os ícones no gráfico

Tags: r, highcharts

O código abaixo está na documentação do *package* `highcharter` ao tópico `hciconarray`:

```
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)

 hciconarray(c("car", "truck", "plane"), c(75, 30, 20), icons = c("car", "truck", "plane")) %>%
   hc_add_theme(
     hc_theme_merge(
       hc_theme_flatdark(),
       hc_theme_null(chart = list(backgroundColor = "#34495e"))
     )
   )
```

Tentei reproduzí-lo, mas os ícones não são gerados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz a tentativa em dois computadores (um com Linux e um com Windows), com as últimas versões do `R` e `R Studio` instaladas. Mas, o problema persiste em ambos.

- Como corrigir este problema e gerar o gráfico com os ícones normalmente?

Comment: Parece ser um erro da função. Se tirar `icons = c("car", "truck", "plane")` aparecem uns ícones, círculos, losangos e quadrados. O mesmo acontece com o exemplo anterior, com `icons = "child"` deixam de aparecer. Talvez enviar um mail ao `maintainer("highcharter")`?